# Over the numerical limitation.

Tags: inequality

Find the upper bound of:
$$\sum^k_{i=1} n_i^2 $$
knowing that:
$$\sum^k_{i=1} n_i = d $$
$$ n_i > 0$$
Please help me with that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "How to limit"?

Comment: There is not enough information to solve this. Take for example $\sum n_i = 5$, it could either be $n_1=1,n_2=4$ or $n_1=2,n_2=3$ but the sum of squares for these is different $17$ vs $13$.

Comment: This is why, I expected him to want an upper bound... but then we may want to require $n_i \geq 0$....

Comment: Yes, I want to upper bound. And you are right. $n_i > 0$

Comment: In that case it's just $d^2$ as one of the above said.

Comment: @mardat Sorry, deleted that comment as Dan made almost the same, but yes.

Comment: Yes, I know it. Because I find something less than $d^2$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
$$\left(\sum^k_{i=1} n_i\right)^2= \sum^k_{i=1} n_i^2 + 2\sum_{1\leq l < j \leq k} n_jn_l $$

Comment: ok, but what about $2\sum_{1\le l \le j \le k } n_jn_l$

Comment: The idea is that you can re-arrange to $\left(\sum^k_{i=1} n_i\right)^2 - 2\sum_{1\leq l < j \leq k} n_jn_l = \sum^k_{i=1} n_i^2$, and since $2\sum_{1\leq l < j \leq k} n_jn_l$ must be positive, $\sum^k_{i=1} n_i^2$ cannot be greater than $d^2$. Remember that $\left(\sum^k_{i=1} n_i\right)^2 = d^2$